# Return numbers in string:postgresql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, select

I have the string: I am 10 years old with 500 friends.
I want to return 10 and 500 but when I executed the query below and it returned empty:

```
SELECT
REGEXP_MATCHES('I have the string: I am 10 years old with 500  friends',
                '-?\\d+','g');
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the double anti-slash. While some databases require regex character classes to be escaped, Postgres expects just one anti-slash.

So:

```
select regexp_matches(
    'I have the string: I am 10 years old with 500 friends',
    '-?\d+',
    'g'
);
```

`'-?'` is not sensible for your example string. I left it as is in case you want to accomodate for possible negative numbers.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e22bb1cd930faddd6fa99e9b5ab52ea5)**

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\\d` with `[0-9]`:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_MATCHES(
    'I have the string: I am 10 years old with 500 friends',
    '(-?[0-9]+)','g'
  )
```

Output:

```
10
500
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/53148).